# Cannot override logout in Django

Tags: django, authentication

I'm trying to override the DJango logout doing the following:

**registration_urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^activate/complete/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/activation_complete.html'),
        name='registration_activation_complete'),
    # Activation keys get matched by \w+ instead of the more specific
    # [a-fA-F0-9]{40} because a bad activation key should still get to the view
    # that way it can return a sensible "invalid key" message instead of a
    # confusing 404.
    url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
        ActivationView.as_view(),
        name='registration_activate'),
    url(r'^register/$',
        FHRegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUserProfile),
        name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^register/complete/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/registration_complete.html'),
        name='registration_complete'),
    (r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),

    #url(r'^login/$', views.login(template_name='registration/login.html'),{'APP_ROOT': settings.APP_ROOT}),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'registration/login.html', 'authentication_form': AuthenticationForm }),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'formshare.apps.main.registration_views.LogoutView'),
)
```

**registration_views.py**

```
...
def LogoutView(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, "registration/logout.html",{'APP_ROOT': settings.APP_ROOT})
...
```

But it does not seem to work! APP_ROOT is defined in the settings and I use it in many other views and templates. But the logout template does not get the variable APP_ROOT

Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you defined APP_ROOT in settings ?

Comment: Yes, I use it in many other places!!!! Bu the def does not seem to do anything! Because if I to a print "Hello!!!" before or after the logout nothing gets out

Comment: You mean this view LogoutView is not getting called ? If this is the case then put logout url on top in url patterns in urls.py

Comment: can you please share your directory structure. thanks.

Comment: Yes  Afnan Nazir . If I put the logout at the top it works! Thanks!